# Integer.parseInt of csv file not working in Java

Tags: java, csv

Im trying to read in information from a csv file into eclipse and then read in each column into respective variables but I keep getting this error. I see that the error is probably occurring at this line of the code

> int accountNUM = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);

The error that I am getting is the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1;PhilJohnston;phil.johnston@gmail.com;"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Verbindung.main(Verbindung.java:55)
```

When I change the the "," to a ";" I receive the following error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at Verbindung.main(Verbindung.java:55)

my csv file is in this format

```
A            b               c
1        PhilJohnston     phil.johnston@gmail.com
```

the corresponding Java code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql. * ;
import oracle.jdbc.driver. * ;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Verbindung {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Importing CSV File for table FUSER
        String filename = "Fuser_excel.csv";
        File file = new File(filename);

        // Creating Arraylist
        ArrayList < FBuser > fuser = new ArrayList < FBuser > ();
        //  ArrayList<Suppliers> lieferant = new ArrayList<Suppliers>();
        //ArrayList<Delivery> lieferung = new ArrayList<Delivery>();

        try {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String data = inputStream.next();
                String[] values = data.split(",");
                int accountNUM = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                String N_AME = values[1];
                //String EMAIL = values[2];
                //System.out.println(accountNUM);
                //creating the object FBuser with the relevant parameters
                //FBuser fbuser = new FBuser(accountNUM,N_AME,EMAIL);
                //fuser.add(fbuser);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException d) {
            d.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // establish connection to database
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String database = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle-lab.cs.univie.ac.at:1521:lab";
            String user = "a01547605";
            String pass = "dbs19";

            // establish connection to database 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, user, pass);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT into fuser (accountNUM, N_AME, EMAIL) values(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            final int batchSize = 1000;
            int count = 0;
            for (FBuser a: fuser) {
                ps.setInt(1, a.getaccountNUM());
                ps.setString(2, a.getN_AME());
                ps.setString(3, a.getEMAIL());
                ps.addBatch();

                if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                    ps.executeBatch();
                }
            }
            ps.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

the corresponding Class
public class FBuser {
    int accountNUM;  
    String N_AME;
    String EMAIL;

    public FBuser(int accountNUM,String N_AME, String EMAIL ) {
        this.accountNUM = accountNUM;
        this.N_AME = N_AME;
        this.EMAIL = EMAIL;
    }

    public int getaccountNUM() {
        return accountNUM;
    }

    public String getN_AME() {
        return N_AME;
    }

    public String getEMAIL() {
        return EMAIL;
}
}
```

I dont understand where im going wrong here. There may be a problem with the csv file itself or just the way its being read in.

Comment: It seems that your CSV file is split by `;` not by `,` (so `data.split(",")` is wrong)

Comment: CSV file content should be separated by commas like this `a,b,c,1,phil`

Comment: I recommend to use a library like Commons CSV for parsing the input file. This handles typical issues like different separators,  headers, etc for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the array returned by `split()` can only be 0 if the string contains solely the delimiter you provided as argument to the method.

For example, `";".split(";").length` returns 0.

That `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused by a line containing only `;`.

If a line in a CSV file only contains delimiters, then it means that all cells are empty. If you want to *get rid* of these lines, you should delete them in your CSV file. If you want to *skip* these lines, then you could simply check if the resulting array is empty:

```
String[] cells = line.split(";");
if (cells.length > 0) {
    // Parse lines
}
// Else do nothing
```

Comment: youre right I realized this as well, but how do I get rid of the line with only a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted as your CSV file there are two issues. First, your separator is not a comma, but a space. Secondly, if you change to space as your separator the first value(value[0]) will be 'A'. Java can't convert 'A' to a number.

Comment: There is actually no title there i just wanted to show that the data was seperated in different columns. I also changed my separator from comma to a space and I still receive the same error.